# Is there a way to hide the Windows Live Messenger button on the task bar in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-messenger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MSN keeps appearing in my task bar](https://superuser.com/questions/157646/msn-keeps-appearing-in-my-task-bar)

Any one found a way to hide the taskbar button of Windows Live Messenger when it is running on Windows 7 ?

It's taking up space I don't want.

Under XP, messenger hid it's button when minimized. Windows 7 always seems to display a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/01/15/workaround-to-hide-and-minimize-windows-live-messenger-iconbutton-to-notification-area-system-tray-in-windows-7/) you'll see a step-by-step guide.

> Exit Windows Live Messenger or MSN
>   Messenger completely (Right click on
>   WLM button/icon on Taskbar and select
>   Exit). Go to Start Menu, locate the
>   Windows Live Messenger shortcut. Tip:
>   It’s also possible to deal directly
>   with the actual WLM program,
>   msnmgsr.exe located in
>   %ProgramFiles%\Windows Live\Messenger\
>   folder.
>
> Right click on the Windows Live
>   Messenger shortcut or executable, and
>   select Properties.
>
> Go to Compatibility tab. Tick the
>   check box for Run this program in
>   compatibility mode for under
>   “Compatibility Mode”, and then select
>   Windows Vista from the drop down list.
>
> Click OK. Run Windows Live Messenger

Comment: It could be nice if you could paste that answer here in case of a probable link rot.

Comment: It's pretty messed up, but it should do the work.
Thanks.